# Why does CSS work differently with local and remote website?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, facebook

I am having a chrome-extension which basically adds **jquery autocompletion** to facebook chatbox.

Now, I want to make the suggestion list menu of autocompletion horizontal.

So, I tried to change the `jquery-ui.css` by testing it on a local html file which I had designed and it contains just a `textarea`.

So, I found that in this CSS file if I make changes in:

**Original:**

```
...
.ui-menu .ui-menu-item a {
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    padding: 2px .4em;
    line-height: 1.5;
    min-height: 0; /* support: IE7 */
    font-weight: normal;
}
```

**Changed:**

```
...
.ui-menu .ui-menu-item a {
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline;
    padding: 2px .4em;
    line-height: 1.5;
    min-height: 0; /* support: IE7 */
    font-weight: normal;
}
```

**PROBLEM:**

`display:block` to `display:inline`, I get a horizontal list. This works properly in local file.

Already tried `!important`, but it doesn't work.

But, when I test same on `https://www.facebook.com/`, it does not work.

**NOTE:**

Also I would like to add, that if I try to make list menu items bold by changing `font-weight:normal` to `font-weight:bold` then this works both in local as well as facebook.

So, how to manage this? Also, please comment below if any part of code is needed, if you want to have a look at it (I did not want to make the question unnecessarily long), then I will include that part of code as soon as possible.

I am quite new to SO, so please comment if you want me to edit the question in any way.

P.S.: I am using **google chrome** and opera web-browsers to test this extension.

Comment: Have you tried adding `!important` at the end on `display:block`? My guess is that facebook is overriding your style.

Comment: Yes, I have already tried `!important`, but doesn't work. I also would like to tell that while watching the html in inspect view, I saw that on every menu change, the `jquery-ui.js` modifies it to become `display:block` back. So I also have added a function to change it back to `inline` after search `respnonse`. However, this shouldn't matter as even without this function, CSS change works fine in local file.

Comment: use display:inline-block; if there is any size involved or content as block element or alike. inline on it's on is not holding anything, inline-block turns to be an inline-box. and has somehow layout wich inline has not.

Comment: Even this, doesn't work. But this works on the local html page.

Comment: @j809 "The local HTML page", is that a copy of the real Facebook page, that you saved to disk?

Comment: No, just a page with a textarea with autocomplete suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got a solution for this.

Adding it here so that it might help somebody else, who would like to have a horizontal autcomplete menu.

Added a `style` tag at top of facebook html page by:

```
var style = $(document).find('body');
$(style).prepend("<style>.ui-menu-item{display:inline;}</style>");
```

You need to have same in jquery-ui CSS file also.

I don't know why the change in jquery-ui CSS file only failed here but adding tag like this solved and made the autocomplete list horizontal.

Thanks for help everyone.

Comment: You add a `<style>` element to the `<body>`? Then the least you should do is give it a `scoped` attribute.